Advanced Search Exports Without Data
When using Advanced Search:

Selecting Display Results As = Related Contacts + Employee of
Selecting the Tags for the related Organizations
The Search Results show 923 Individual Contact Records (as expected)

When I "Select All Records" > "Export Contacts", the export shows only the field headers regardless if I use the default "Export PRIMARY Fields" or "Select fields for export".
I do NOT have an issue exporting data when not altering "Display Results As" (#1, above)
Is this a know issue and/or a way to fix this?
Using Civi Version 5.78.3, Joomla 5.2.1
** Update - I found a workaround for this, BUT am still hoping to resolve why this is not working from the Advanced Search Window...

After the search, instead of selecting all records and then selecting "export" from Actions, you can select "Group - add contacts" or "Group - create smart group".

From >Contacts >Manage Groups, Select "Contacts" on the right side of the screen and from the list of contacts Window, export from there (via actions, same as you would from the search results). The export works regardless of which fields are present/selected/populated.



It might be worth testing if you have similar outcome on one of the master sites (latest code) eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Thank you petednz - fuzion. I did this, got the same result as I noted above, plus a string of warnings (related to demo install?): Example of one line: * Warning: Undefined array key "postal_greeting" in content_674dd9a1bd6538_65485941() (line 123 of /srv/buildkit/build/dmaster/.civibuild/private/default/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/15/f0/4f/15f04f388b4c993dbe34e2da704eb915b9d857a7_0.file_Select.tpl.php).
